# Identify the /var/lib/docker/containers/$ID/ docker directory

Tags: docker

I need to know which docker (running or not) is associated to the big directory /var/lib/docker/containers/$ID/ :

```bash
$ id=d28ebf088353dd7135488f447df2a2be6f7bc84df44298bc1a869a78d8a943f2
$ du -sh /var/lib/docker/containers/$id/
21G     d28ebf088353dd7135488f447df2a2be6f7bc84df44298bc1a869a78d8a943f2/
$ docker image ls -a --no-trunc | grep $id
$ docker images -a --no-trunc | grep $id
$
```

Comment: `ps -e | grep dockerd` will find you Docker's process ID; there should normally be only one.  You should almost never have reason to look in `/var/lib/docker`; what's your actual goal with this sequence?

Comment: @DavidMaze The filesystem `/` is full.

Comment: @DavidMaze Your command does not tell me which docker object is using the directory `/var/lib/docker/containers/$id/`.

Comment: [How to analyze disk usage of a Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26753087/how-to-analyze-disk-usage-of-a-docker-container) suggests `docker ps --size` (and, again, completely ignoring `/var/lib/docker`).  This doesn't really seem like a programming-related question, though.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is 'how do I know which container owns this directory", then you just need to pass your `id` to the `ps` filter:

`docker ps -a -f $id`